# telegram-bot python | TypeError: mute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

im creating a im creating a telegram bot using python and i have created a function that just gets the orginal messag's users id by a reply of another user...

let me explain,

---

incase there are A & B in a telegram group,

A : "hi"

B : tags/replies to A's "hi" by "/info"

in this case i need how does the bot in the group get A's info by the "/info" given (replied) out by B?

---

so i wrote a piece of code to check that :

```
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

from typing import Optional, List

from telegram import Message, Chat, Update, Bot, User
from telegram.error import BadRequest
from telegram.ext.dispatcher import run_async
from telegram.utils.helpers import mention_html


updater = Updater("1262215479:AAHtwK5J-6lP8iw9b7uRjcOaazelRkHgq3s", use_context=True)
dp = updater.dispatcher


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def mute(bot: Bot, update: Update, args):
    chat = update.effective_chat  # type: Optional[Chat]
    user = update.effective_user  # type: Optional[User]
    message = update.effective_message  # type: Optional[Message]
    user_id = extract_user(message, args)
    member = chat.get_member(int(user_id))
    print("hey1")


def main():
    
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("promote", mute))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and i get  'TypeError: mute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'' error

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get an error is that args needs an argument but what you mean is
`*args` with an asterisk.